# Read json map string in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, each

I'm trying to read json string map in jQuery. I tried the below way but getting:

> Invalid operand a error

Any help is appreciated.

```
var data = '{"Category1":["A","B","C"],"Category2":["P","Q","R"]}';

$.each(data, function(k,v) {
    console.log(k + " " + v);

    $.each(v, function(item) {
        console.log(k + "-" + item);
    }
});
```

Expecting Category1 - A, Category1 - B ...

Comment: var data is string not object..

Comment: Your `data` variable is String to use `$.each` you should to convert string to JSON use `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little change in @abpatil answer, this what exactly you want.

```js
var data='{"Category1":["A","B","C"],"Category2":["P","Q","R"]}';

$.each(JSON.parse(data), function (k, v) {
    console.log(k + " "+ v);
    $.each(v, function (i, data) {
        console.log(k + ' - ', data);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse json string.
Try following code-

```js
var data='{"Category1":["A","B","C"],"Category2":["P","Q","R"]}';
//use JSON.parse to parse a JSON string
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function( k,v) {
    console.log(k +" "+v);
    $.each(v, function(item) {
            console.log(k +"-"+item);
    });//here you missed closing bracket 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `v[item]` as you have to fetch the items of array by their index.

```js
var data={"Category1":["A","B","C"],"Category2":["P","Q","R"]};

$.each(data, function( k,v) {
    console.log(k +" "+v);
    $.each(v, function(item) {
      console.log(k +"-"+v[item]);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```